# .bind('scroll'), add animation or reduce "bounce"

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

This is a jQuery script I'm using to have the menu fixed when users scroll the page. **[This](http://ffio.it/randevu/)** is a live demo.

```
<script>
var num = 170; //number of pixels before modifying styles

$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
        $('#header').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('#header').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
</script>

<style>
.fixed {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    background-color:#e4e4e4;
    width:100% !important;
    background-image: url("images/logo_small.png") !important;
    background-size:20px auto !important;
    margin:0 auto !important;
    padding:20px 0 10px !important;
    background-position:90px center !important;
    z-index:1;
}


#header {
    background-image: url("images/logo.png");
    background-position: 30px 5px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 152px auto;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 18px auto 0;
    padding: 60px 0 87px 100px;
    width: 780px;
}
</style>
```

Problem is, as you can see, when "small" menu appears there's a "jump", and the content goes up abruptly.

Comment: you can not animate the position of element so you should try to animate height of header.
other method is to set header position fixed and animate it to top(or animate margin) according to the requirement
like i did on this site http://vidadbox.com/about/

Comment: Thanks, I managed to adapt it to my website. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/andaywells/jVy5L/64/embedded/result/

```
var num = 170; //number of pixels before modifying styles

$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {

    $('#header').addClass('fixed');


} else {
    $('#header').removeClass('fixed');

}
});
```

I removed the fadeout, and added position: fixed; to the header, so using css transitions, the scroll is much more fluid.

Comment: Thanks! I'm from my phone now but as soon as I arrive at hone I'll test it :-)

Comment: uhm.. doesn't seem to do much: http://www.rendezvousroma.it/new/index3.html (try with firefox, with it it's more fluid and you see better the issue)

Comment: check this demo for neater/ better code looks much better: http://jsfiddle.net/andaywells/YyVeX/49/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

Check this url
[relative sidebar to fixed, when it reaches the end of window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384047/relative-sidebar-to-fixed-when-it-reaches-the-end-of-window)

```
  $(function() {      
    $(window).scroll(function(evt) {
        var top = $('#header').offset().top;
        var sidebartop = $('#header').height() / 2;
        var y = $(this).scrollTop() - sidebartop;
        if (y > top) {
                $('#header').addClass('fixed').css( "top",  -top -sidebartop + 220)
            }
        else {
            $('#header').removeClass('fixed');
            $('#header').css( "top", "auto" );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried but now when I scroll nothing happens.. link: www.rendezvousroma.it/index2.html

Comment: I'll give this a try soon :-)

Answer (score 0):

This will definitely help you.

example: http://www.inserthtml.com/2013/07/scroll-header-animations/

demo: http://www.inserthtml.com/demo/header-animations/example-1/